# Iterate over object and break

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
const locales = {
  RU: 'something here',
  EN: 'something else here',
};

let locale;
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(locales)) {
  if (key.indexOf('RU') !== -1) {
    locale = value;
    break;
  }
}
```

I am however using eslint. It's complaining about `no-restricted-syntax`, so I'm wondering how i can achieve the same result without a for loop (iteration with breaking).

ES7 is welcome to be used.

Comment: please add some examples of valid keys with `RU` or are you looking for exactly `RU` as key?

Comment: You can do something like this: `locale = locales[Object.keys(locales).find(k => k.indexOf("RU") != -1)];`

Comment: @NinaScholz Done!

Comment: @Titus Spot on, post an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
const locales = {
  RUSSIAN: 'something here',
  ENGLISH: 'something else here',
};
let locale = locales[Object.keys(locales).find(k => k.indexOf("RU") != -1)];
console.log(locale);
```

Comment: You get a plus for guessing that it was Russian and English ;)

Answer (score 2):

You could access directly with the given key.

```
locale = locales.RU;
```

Or

```
var key = 'RU',
    locale = locales[key];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a function and call `return`

Comment: Without using a for loop he said.

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript's [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) Function.
Something like this:

```
Object.entries(locales).find((value, key) -> key.indexOf("RU") !== -1);
```